# how to make gridcolumn type boolean check base on parsing

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

In my firstform, the gridview shows this:
[image]

and then i want to parsing to secondform iam using this code

```
string asscode = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("AsstCode").ToString();
Assistant assist = new Assistant(asscode);
assist.show();
```

When parsing, the string is one variable, so i need to split them. I'm using this `split` to break them

```
string ass_code;
public Assistant(string z) //this is form 2
{
  InitializeComponent();           
  ass_code = z;
}
```

in second form i already set a `gridview.datasource` from another `query` and so i need to add custom column to the `gridview`, iam using this code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  string[] names = ass_code.Split(';');
  gridView1.BeginUpdate();
  DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(Boolean));
  GridColumn column = gridView1.Columns.AddVisible(col.ColumnName);
  column.Caption = col.Caption;
  column.Name = col.ColumnName;
  gridView1.EndUpdate();
 }
```

for the secondform interface, the gridview display this

[image]

what i want to ask is

1. how do i make the `column x` got checked base on the `asscode` so `0110300` and `0110164` and the other value not checked. as you can see on `column x` it got `gray` colour which the value is not `1 or 0`
2. when i try to

   ```
       //string[] names = ass_code.Split(';');
       //foreach (string xy in names)
       //{
       //    MessageBox.Show(xy);
       //}
   ```

   it shows that the first was `0110159` but the second string `0110164` got space string on the first character. << because this use for `list 1`

**UPDATE**:
well iam using this code but its only check on `0110300` because it set `0110159` back to `false`

```
foreach (string x in names)
{
     string[] names = ass_code.Split(';');
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {

                string xg = x.Trim();
                string g = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["code"].ToString().Trim();
                if (g == xg)
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "Dada", true);

                }
                else
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "Dada", false);
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE2**

[image]

Comment: At first you have to split out of your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You make to much handy stuff. The Devexpress Grid is really much simpler to use:

```
var data = //GETYOURDATA
gridControl.DataSource = data;
```

This populates your data to the grid. You even don't need to create any columns etc. If you want a value now, you shouldn't use `GetRowCellValue();` Try to use your DataSource instead.

```
var actualRow = gridView.GetFocusedRow() as DataRowView;
MessageBox(actualRow["code"]); //Will print your code from code column
```

What you need to understand is that your DataSource is the source of trues and the GridView just show this data. This becomes more comfortable if you store your data in `List<T>`.

EXAMPLE:

```
public class Employee()
{
   public int Code{get;set}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public bool X {get{return Code == 0110300}}
   public static List<Employee> ReadAll(){//Get your data};
}

public class MyForm() : XtraForm
{
   var data = Employee.ReadAll();
   gridControl.DataSource = data;

   //Access Employee code
   Employee emp = gridView.GetFocusedRow() as Employee;
   MessageBox.Show(emp.Code.ToString());
}
```

**UPDATE**
Use the second approach from @Rupesh to remove your spaces. And uses Equals for string comparison. Further set your GridColumn 'X' to `column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Bool;` to make sure DevExpress don't override your data.

**UPDATE-2**

```
var names = ass_code.Split(';').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
      for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
      {
         string g = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["code"].ToString().Trim();
         if (names.Contains(g))
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "Dada", true);
         else
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "Dada", false);
     }
```

Comment: man, i almost finish it up. do you mind  checking the update?

Comment: use the second approach from @Rupesh to remove your spaces. And uses Equals for string comparison.

Comment: i think i have already use trim(). the thing is the logic of foreach, its like when iam already discover the first digit `0110300` its set to true, then when it got back to `foreach` function where the digit was `0110054` it run the `for` function the digit that already set `true` it set back to `false`

Comment: iam sorry it doest work, at first i think its only check the first value, but then when i debug it , the second value still got the space character... ill post it

Comment: sorry i fixed this

Answer (score 0):

If leading / trailing spaces is cause of issue then you can do it in two ways:

first way:

```
string[] names = ass_code.Split(';');
// remove leading / trailing spaces
for (int i = names.Length-1; i >= 0; i-- )
    names[i] = names[i].Trim();
```

second way:

```
string[] names = ass_code.Split(new char[] { ';', ' '},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```